# 12.04 - unable to install on toshiba laptop

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, wubi

I having problem to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my toshiba laptop preloaded with Windows 7. It fails to install using windows installer after downloading files, I tried to reinstall it and it still refused.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to install 12.04 using wubi alongside windows? What exactly happens once you download ubuntu ISO?, What it means refused? What error you receive? Please update your questions with further information about your installation problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can (1) burn the ubuntu iso as disk (2)use the disk to boot your computer (3) install ubuntu alongside with your windows 7 (4) install grub to manage all the installed system.

it is not necessary to stick into installing ubuntu from windows.